# Is it possible to restore active filename to window title bar in ubuntu 16.04 Unity?

Tags: unity, 16.04

I recently upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04.  I have been annoyed by several seemingly arbitrary and unnecessary changes to Unity, but the one that really makes me want to abandon Unity is the loss of the active filename from the titlebar in several applications, among them gedit and gimp.  In 14.04, when working in either of these applications, the name/path of the active file were displayed in the title bar, at the same level as the min/max/close buttons, above the menu bar.  In 16.04, using Unity, the min/max/close buttons are on the same level as the menu, and the active file name/path is not there at all.  Depending on the particular program, it may be elsewhere in the window, but it's no longer in the title bar.  I would like to find a way to restore it to the title bar.  So far, I've found ways to get rid of the #$%^ overlay scroll bars, and restore the incremental arrows on the legacy scroll bars, but I haven't found a way to solve this problem.  Is there a way to do this?  If I use something other than Unity, like Gnome Flashback, or Cinnamon, this doesn't happen.  But this and some of the other idiot changes made to Unity have me tearing my hair - and I can't afford that.

Comment: It's really not the end of the world. Unity is just a shell, one of many.

Comment: Yes, and it happens to be the one I'd prefer to use.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug. I don't have GIMP installed, but for Gedit, all you have to do is hover your mouse over the title menu and move the mouse away. Then the window title will return. You might have to click on one of the menu buttons, then click elsewhere.